# Problem with FontAwesome and ngModel when adding PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem in my angular app. When I add the PWA doing `ng add @angular/pwa`, it just breaks things that were working fine in production until adding PWA.

For example, FontAwesome icons. It says this:

```
'fa-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
```

Also, I have an NgModel directive to check if the input has text or not, and it gives me this error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

I have already imported the **FormsModule** in the **app.module.ts** so it should not give such error, and, as I said before, the app was fully working until I added the PWA, so I suspect the error comes from that.